# Pure virtual method return a class type using copy constructor in C++

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, deep-copy, pure-virtual

I'm doing something called "deep copy", the clone() method requires to return a new instance of the derived class type using its copy constructor

Device.h

```
class Device : public Object{
public:
    Device();
    Device(const Device& copy);
    ~Device();
    virtual Device* clone() = 0;
};
```

Radar.h

```
class Radar : public Device {
public:
    Radar();
    ~Radar();
    Radar(const Radar &Copy);
    Device* clone();
};
```

Radar.cpp

```
Radar::Radar() {
}

Radar::Radar(const Radar& copy) {
}

Radar::~Radar() {
}

Device* Radar::clone() {
}
```

I have no idea how to deal with this method using copy constructor, anyone who can help me?

Comment: You have nothing to clone.  Does you class actually have some member variables?

Comment: Yes. It has some members. I removed them for easy to read

Answer (score 4):

**Note:** You may want to consider using `Radar* clone() override;` in the derived class, which would allow an instance of the derived type to clone itself and maintain the same type (this is known as a covariant return type).

> return a new instance of the derived class type using its copy constructor

```
return new Radar(*this);
```

- `new` because you need a pointer to a new instance of the class
- `*this` because the copy constructor signature is `Radar(const Radar&)`

Comment: You can use the [CRTP](https://katyscode.wordpress.com/2013/08/22/c-polymorphic-cloning-and-the-crtp-curiously-recurring-template-pattern/) to avoid implementing this for every derived class.

Comment: It's really helpful. Thank you very much.

Comment: @JoeyZhang You should consider the CRTP approach mentioned by [Matthäus Brandl](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1969455/matth%c3%a4us-brandl) if you want to avoid the tedium (i.e., maintenance burden) they mention.

Answer (score 1):

A class with virtual functions usually has no copy constructor, because it usually does not make sense to copy objects of such classes. Allowing the copy constructor opens the door to all kinds of dangerous bugs related to slicing.

In other words (emphasis by me):

> I'm doing something called "deep copy", the clone() method **requires** to
>   return a new instance of the derived class type using its copy
>   constructor

No, it does absolutely **not require** a copy constructor. It should prevent copying by deleting the copy constructor and the copy assignment operator.

Here is an example of how this should be done. Note that I've made the destructor virtual and that I've added some example members. I've also changed `clone`'s signature to be `const` and used `override` to enable additional compilation checks.

```
class Device : public Object {
public:
    Device() {}
    Device(const Device&) = delete;
    Device& operator=(const Device&) = delete;
    virtual ~Device() {}
    virtual Device* clone() const = 0;
};

class Radar : public Device {
public:
    Radar(int i, const std::string& s) : i(i), s(s) {}
    Radar* clone() const override 
    {
        return new Radar(i, s);
    }
private:
    int i;
    std::string s;
};
```

Depending on what your design requires, the `Radar` constructor invoked by `clone` could also be `private`.

Another thing is that you might want to consider a `std::unique_ptr`-based design:

```
class Device : public Object {
public:
    Device() {}
    Device(const Device&) = delete;
    Device& operator=(const Device&) = delete;
    virtual ~Device() {}
    virtual std::unique_ptr<Device> clone() const = 0;
};

class Radar : public Device {
public:
    Radar(int i, const std::string& s) : i(i), s(s) {}
    std::unique_ptr<Device> clone() const override 
    {
        return std::make_unique<Radar>(i, s);
    }
private:
    int i;
    std::string s;
};
```

Comment: Just to be clear, your statement about deleting the copy constructor is only referring to the base class and not the derived class, correct? If you're also talking about the derived class then why should `Radar r(0, ""); ... r = other;` (where `other`'s type is `Radar`) be disallowed?

Comment: FYI, I'm just trying to make sure I understand your advice and its rationale.

Comment: @JamesAdkison: Disallowing the copy constructor and copy assignment operator in the base class automatically disallows both functions for all derived classes.